# Looking for the name of this font

Tags: font-identification

I am looking for this font. It is similar to Lithos, but it is handtooled. Does anyone know the name of it?

[image: what the font]

Answer (score 5):

This type will be [**Linolschrift Font Family**](http://www.1001fonts.com/linolschrift-font.html)

---

[image]